# How to get attribute name dynamically in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have this query:-

```
select distinct pav.ProductID,pav.String_Value as Description ,pav1.String_Value as StockNumber,pav2.String_Value as ProductImage,
pav3.String_Value as SpecSheet,pav4.String_Value as Price
from core.ProductAttributesValues pav join core.Attribute a on pav.AttributeID=a.ID and a.Name='Description'
inner join core.ProductAttributesValues pav1 on pav1.ProductID=pav.ProductID
inner join core.Attribute a1 on pav1.AttributeID=a1.ID and a1.Name='StockNumber'
inner join core.ProductAttributesValues pav2 on pav2.ProductID=pav1.ProductID 
inner join core.Attribute a2 on pav2.AttributeID=a2.ID and a2.Name='ProductImage'
inner join core.ProductAttributesValues pav3 on pav3.ProductID=pav2.ProductID 
inner join core.Attribute a3 on pav3.AttributeID=a3.ID and a3.Name='SpecSheet'
inner join core.ProductAttributesValues pav4 on pav4.ProductID=pav3.ProductID 
inner join core.Attribute a4 on pav4.AttributeID=a4.ID and a4.Name='Price'
```

**I want to pass a1.Names(i.e:- Description ,StockNumber, ProductImage, etc), dynamically.**

Comment: Are you really running this query on 4 different versions of SQL Server?!

Comment: That's not how Stackoverflow works. Now people have no idea what you are really doing and don't trust your question.

Comment: `No just in sql server` ... David was asking which _version_ of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: Snippet removed because this isn't a UI or CSS question.

Comment: @Sanjiv, What SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: dynamically means ??

Comment: So you tagged all versions of SQL Server except the one you are actually using? Brilliant!

Comment: @NazirUllah:- Here in my above query i am showing column name(i.e:- Description, StockNumber, ProductImage, etc) from attribute table and for those columns i am getting data from different  table(productattributevalues) for that i have  joined productattributevalues and attribute table multiples times and passing the name statically(eg a1.name=description ) .so i want to pass these names dynamically.

Comment: Always use where condition for filter please don't over ON condition on join. it really sucks

Comment: Is there any solution for that..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT 
    pav.ProductID
    ,CASE WHEN a.Name = 'Description'   THEN pav.String_Value ELSE NULL END AS Description
    ,CASE WHEN a.Name = 'StockNumber'   THEN pav.String_Value ELSE NULL END AS StockNumber
    ,CASE WHEN a.Name = 'ProductImage'  THEN pav.String_Value ELSE NULL END AS ProductImage
    ,CASE WHEN a.Name = 'SpecSheet'     THEN pav.String_Value ELSE NULL END AS SpecSheet    
    ,CASE WHEN a.Name = 'Price'         THEN pav.String_Value ELSE NULL END AS Price    
FROM core.ProductAttributesValues pav
INNER JOIN core.Attribute a ON pav.AttributeID = a.ID
    AND a.name IN ('Description', 'StockNumber', 'ProductImage', 'SpecSheet','Price')
```